# Write simple test for api call

Tags: ios, swift

I want to write a test for function that interact with API. I ended up with:

```
class FileDownloaderTests: XCTestCase {

    // MARK: timeouts

    let regularTimeout: TimeInterval = 10
    let largeTimeout: TimeInterval = 15

    func testDownload() {
        // URLS.firstFileUrl.rawValue
        let downloader = FileDownloader(string: URLS.firstFileUrl.rawValue)
        downloader.download(successCompletion: {
            XCTAssertTrue(true)
        }) { error in
            print("error in test - \(error)")
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: largeTimeout, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

So, it suppose to wait largeTimeout(15 seconds) for successCompletion closure, then test should be passed. But it ended up with an error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FileDownloaderTests.FileDownloaderTests waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-14460.20/Sources/XCTestFramework/Async/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.m:28
/Users/Necrosoft/Documents/Programming/Work/Life-Pay/FileDownloader/FileDownloaderTests/FileDownloaderTests.swift:28: error: -[FileDownloaderTests.FileDownloaderTests testDownload] : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "API violation - call made to wait without any expectations having been set."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `fulfill` the expectation to tell the expectation that it can stop waiting/the process has finished

```
func testDownload() {
    // URLS.firstFileUrl.rawValue
    let downloader = FileDownloader(string: URLS.firstFileUrl.rawValue)
    downloader.download(successCompletion: {
        XCTAssertTrue(true)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }) { error in
        print("error in test - \(error)")
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: largeTimeout, handler: nil)
}
```

Note: it is generally not a good idea to run automated tests against a live API. You should either use a stubbed response to just test that your handling of the code is correct or at least test against a test/staging API.

EDIT: you have two completion handlers so I called fulfill in each

Comment: what is - expectation?

Comment: Expectation tells the unit test/running code that it needs to wait for something, fulfilling it tells it that it has finished. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500899-expectation) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations)

Answer (score 0):

use below example to create your own test

func testLogin() throws {
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "DeviceID register with URL")

```
    NetworkAPI.shared.loginRequest(username: "zdravko.zdravkin", password: "password") { authenticated in
             switch authenticated {
             case true:
                 XCTAssertTrue(true, "authenticated")
             case false:
                 XCTFail("wrong username, password or deviceID")
             }
         }

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
}
```